# Double slash in path to media files

Tags: python, django, url, path, os.path

I have django app (very old version 1.0.4), and I have problem with building path, in this case to media files.

When my variable in settings is:

`MEDIA_URL_WWWW = '/'`

I get a path where there is no `/` between `media` and `content`- 
`domain.net/admin/files/mediacontent/`

But when my variable has a double slash `//`.

`MEDIA_URL_WWWW = '//'`

I get a path where there is a double `//` between media and content
`domain.net/admin/files/media//content/`

Comment: `MEDIA_URL_WWWW` doesn't seem to be a standard Django config variable…  you'd need to check the rest of your code

Comment: Can you provide the your full settings file?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware - Django 1.0.4 is so old that there isn't even an official documentation and it will be insecure. You should really consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Django and do not know if my answer applies to it, but did you try a raw string `r'/'` ? Alternatively for path related issues, I usually use the os.path.join function , i.e.

```
from os.path import join
mypath = join('media', 'content')
```